# ListView.builder NetworkImage reflection

Tags: flutter, listview, dart

Colleagues!

What’s might be wrong with a code below? A smartphone does not show anything.

Thanks.

https://gist.github.com/cripnail/1b8007f7cca304e647fb16fa91e0a957

Comment: Where's the code?

Comment: go to `Project folder -> android -> main` and add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` to `AndroidManifest.xml` file

Comment: I've just added permission.INTERNET. However it does not solve the problem:-(